# Saving grid data after cell editing event, sometimes array is empty

Tags: angular, typescript, ag-grid, angular10

I'm using `ag-grid` in my project. After a cell has been edited, I'm trying to persist the `rowData` to the backend. It works for most of the time, but sometimes, I end up persisting a serialized empty array, for a reason that eludes me at the moment.

Right now, I'm using the `onCellEditingStopped` event to trigger the saving to database. Some code from my component:

```
this.plansGridOptions.onCellEditingStopped = this.cellEditingStopped;

cellEditingStopped(params: CellEditingStoppedEvent) { 

    let context = <ImportSessionComponent>params.context;
    context.saveSession().subscribe(r => { });

}

saveSession(): Observable<any> {
    //I'm simply serializing the row data array, and storing that value
    //But sometimes, plansRowData is empty at this point.
    this.importForm.get("uploadItemsSerialized").setValue(JSON.stringify(this.plansRowData));
    return this.importService.saveSession(this.importForm);
}


saveSession(sessionForm: FormGroup): Observable<any> {
    //some conversion from string to number so viewmodel binding works in the backend
    const value = {
        ...sessionForm.value, importType: +sessionForm.get("importType").value, environment: 
        +sessionForm.get("environment").value,
        id: +sessionForm.get("id").value, version: +sessionForm.get("version").value, stepIndex: 
        sessionForm.get("currentStep").value
    };
    return this.http.post<any>("/import/save", value);
}
```

Here's the template markup for the grid:

```
<ag-grid-angular #planGrid style="width: 100%; height: 475px;"
    class="ag-theme-balham-dark"
    [rowData]="plansRowData"
    [gridOptions]="plansGridOptions"
    [columnDefs]="plansRowConfig">
</ag-grid-angular>
```

Seems like the binding between the grid component and my component's array is not always sticking (ie: the event I'm using is triggered before the grid has updated the plansRowData array?) Should I use a different event to trigger the save ? What could be causing the issue ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe switching to `cellValueChanged` would help? That seems sensible as it should, in theory, be fired once a value has been changed - removing any issue of data not being updated before you handle it. Possibly more suitable than the `onCellEditingStopped` (not sure of the various lifecycle order of the hooks).

I know there are some fun things that AG Grid does with timings - there's more than one place I have the odd `setTimeout` function in place to trigger something (usually resizing) in such a way that it actually works.

[API](https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-events/#reference-editing) ref.